# android googlemap with gps

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I am working on a Google map project with GPS. This shows my current location well. Everything works fine. Now I am planning to upgrade my project. I do have few queries:

How can I send my location to others and know where other people on my circle who have same app installed?

For example, 5 of us are using same app and we want to know the location of each other. For this I want to set my username which should be visible to others and in the same way I should know who is at what location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your current needs, the easiest solution it's to post each user location to a central server, and retrieve the location of the others from the server. You could add the logic in the app server to only return location from people nearby, using your own criteria to define what nearby means.
It's recommended to use REST style web services.
You can set up your own server or use other integrated solutions out there like openshift, google engine, parse, etc.